# Interrupt C++ thread which runs Java static method through JNI

Tags: c++, multithreading, java-native-interface, interrupt

Currently I use the following code:

```
void MonkeyRunner::Run(std::string monkey, std::string tablename, std::string confdir) {
  monkey_runner_ = boost::thread([&] {
  env_ = MiniCluster::CreateVM(&jvm_);
...
  env_->CallStaticObjectMethod(runner_class_, runner_method, args);
});
```

`env_` is `(JNIEnv *)`.
The `runner_method` is long running.

I tried calling `monkey_runner_.interrupt()` which didn't seem to have effect.

Hint on how to stop the thread is welcome.

Comment: If you've called `AttachThread()`, as you should have, it is also a Java thread, and can be interrupted in the usual Java way: but that won't have any effect unless the called method does something interruptible or checks for interrupts periodically itself.

Comment: I added call to AttachCurrentThread() : https://pastebin.com/6A4z1UGc I also make the loop in Java respond to InterruptedException. However, I don't see the effect of interruption.